# Time driven simulation backwards steps

Tags: simulink

I am looking for an alternative to Simulink that would allow to control the stepping mechanism. The same concern was raised in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42646463/480225), that Simulink does not allow backwards stepping, so that complex systems x(t,u) where "changing variables" (t <- -t) requires weeks of work, cannot be controlled (u) correctly due to interdependance between past states and present decisions (u=f(x(s)),s<=t).

Conceptually, the trick simply consists in manually storing previous states in memory : for a Simulink *user*, this is difficult and error prone, whereas really simply stepping backwards in time would be simple and fit nicely in Simulink, from the *developer*'s point of view.

Comment: Potentially this link contains relevant code but it seems to require additional effort because it is designed in view of one particular application : http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/61event/